# Google TaskQueue JSON API - Can not oauth - 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, task-queue, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to use the Google JSON API - taskqueue/v1beta2

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/taskqueue/v1beta2/taskqueue.tasks.list

I am not able to successfully authenticate for this service using the API explorer. I can use other JSON APIs like the storage API under the same project & account. When I go the the APIs tab in the developer console there is nothing listed for "TaskQueue" or "TaskQueue JSON API".

Edit: The oauth flow seems to work correctly, with scopes:
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue.consumer

No matter what I do I get a 403 Forbidden response. How can I authorize my account to use the TaskQueue API? Here is my response from the API explorer:

```
403 Forbidden

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  146
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Mon, 19 Jan 2015 17:20:50 GMT
expires:  Mon, 19 Jan 2015 17:20:50 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "you are not allowed to make this api call"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "you are not allowed to make this api call"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API only works for pull queues, and you need to also specify the email address of the user you are authorizing as in your queue.yaml. From the docs:

```
queue:
- name: pull-queue
  mode: pull
  acl:
- user_email: bar@foo.com        # can list, get, lease, delete, and update   tasks
  - writer_email: user@gmail.com # can insert tasks
  - writer_email: bar@foo.com    # can insert tasks, in addition to rights granted by being a user_email above
```

**Defining pull queues**
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Python_Defining_pull_queues

Comment: Any idea why GAE PHP docs detail the REST API, despite Pull Queues not working on GAE PHP?